# InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 2745600 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1152 Function call stack: t

Tags: tensorflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q67U.png)

```
 58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
```

---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 2745600 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1152
[[node sequential_22/flatten_16/Reshape (defined at :7) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_10260]

Function call stack:
train_function

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Welcome! I'd echo the first comment. In addition, it would be helpful to know what you're trying to do here as context.